# C# Strange behavior with arrays and Random.NextDouble()

Tags: c#, arrays, random

I have the following code in the `main()` method:

```
    const int Length = 20;
    const int NumberOfExperiments = 100;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random gen = new Random();
        double[][] arr = new double[NumberOfExperiments][];
        for (int j = 0; j < NumberOfExperiments; ++j)
        {
            arr[j] = new double[Length + 4];
            for (int i = 0; i < Length; ++i)
            {
                arr[j][i] = gen.NextDouble();
            }
            arr[j][Length] = bubbleSort(arr[j]);
            arr[j][Length + 1] = insertSort(arr[j]);
            arr[j][Length + 2] = arr[j][Length] - arr[j][Length + 1];
            arr[j][Length + 3] = arr[j][Length + 2] * arr[j][Length + 2];
            foreach(double memb in arr[j]){
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", memb);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        WriteExcel(arr, "sorting");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

After the first ReadKey() i have the following output:

> 0
>   0
>   0
>   0 
>   0.046667384
>   0.178001223
>   0.197902503
>   0.206131403
>   0.24464349
>   0.306212793
>   0.307806501
>   0.354127458
>   0.385836004
>   0.389128544
>   0.431109518
>   0.489858235
>   0.530548627
>   0.558604611
>   0.647516463
>   0.762527595
>   0.874646365
>   152
>   -151.1253536
>   22838.87251

I don't know why the first several elements of array are filled with 0. The first iteration always begins with `i=0`(or `j=0`), so it's Ok.
Functions `bubbleSort()` and `insertSort()` work correctly and return the number of swaps.
I have used C# for several years, but I really can't understand why this code doesn't work.

Comment: Are you asking why you have the zeros or are you asking why the last two values are so different than the rest?

Comment: You might want to look into [nullable types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx?ppud=4), e.g. `int?`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create the "row", you do this:

```
arr[j] = new double[Length + 4];
```

But then loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Length; ++i)
```

So the last 4 elements are left with the default value (0). When you sort, these elements go to the beginning.

Comment: @user3051029 Then apparently the methods you're using to create those values are returning `0`

Comment: Yes, it's called a declaration. You declare like this: int x;

Comment: @luk32 He means uninitialized by user code, so not having been set a value other than the default value for that type.

Comment: @luk32 yes they are initialized to default value. actualy _uninitialized_ is kind a misleading here. _they are initiliazed to default value_ would be more appropriate.

Comment: @Selman22 No problem with changing the wording to be more clear. Done :)

Comment: I was asking, because I had cases when the compiler did not compile the code for this very reason i.e. "value might not be initialized"-related stuff. I guess it might have been technically important at some cases. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: @luk32 Its mostly just trying to say: "Hey, you are using the variable that never gets assigned to anything! Are you *sure* you wanted to do that?"

Comment: I don't think it asks. It's an error: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y7h161d.aspx . I mean it's not legal in managed code, as I understand it.

Comment: @luk32 I must of been thinking of the warning generated when a value is initialized but never assigned afterwards. Sorry for the confusion. It wouldn't trip in *this* code because that error doesn't check that you initialize every member of an array.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like bubbleSort() gets an array and sorts it, at the time of the call the last 4 elements are empty (set to 0), so they go to the beginning in the result. Check if bubbleSort() uses Array.Length somewhere and make sure it subtracts 4 there.